# emacs not loading packages in terminal under mac osx

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

I'm using emacs 24.5.1 under Mac OS X.

I've no issue using it with the graphical interface, but if I launch it in the terminal app it doesn't load any packages: commands like `package-list` or `linun-mode` give no matches. How do I get emacs to load those packages?

Answer (score 3):

When you launch the terminal app, it might be defaulting to the OSX pre-installed version of emacs (v22). One solution is to create an alias to point to your other installation.

Try launching it from the terminal by using the complete path in your command, with the -nw switch, and see if that helps. If the packages are loaded, and you verify the version as 24.5.1, then the alias would work for you.